# loop all tables in directory and import specific row based on string R

Tags: r

So I have to import some data into R and find it reasonably difficult.

I have multiple similar tables in a directory and would like to make a script looks for specific row (based on string not raw number) and add them to a new table.

Example data:
Table one:

```
name Johnny
registeration data 01012001
userid>= 47
```

table two:

```
name Jimmy
registeration data 02052005
userid>= 1972
```

What I want is a table that contains:

```
userid>= 47
userid>= 1972
```

Note: separated by tap..

What I tried to do is the following:

A: Create a list of files in the working directory:

```
list = (Sys.glob("*.table"))
```

B: created one a table using lappy:

```
table <- lapply(list, function(x) read.table(x, header = FALSE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE))
```

C. Tried to grep the word "userid" (failed):

```
table[grep("userid", rownames("userid")), ]
Error: incorrect number of dimensions
```

Is there a 'simpler way' to fitch row of interest (userid>= in the example) based on string without relying on external packages? I can also think about using "grep userid *.table > newtable" in bash, but I want to use only R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (given that the rownames are in the first variable as in your example):

```
# list all tables in current directory, optionally recursively

tbls <- list.files(getwd(),'.table$') # if more dirs, maybe add recursive = TRUE
# create a list of tables
tbls_r <- lapply(tbls,function(x) read.table(x,header=FALSE,sep='\t',stringAsFactors = FALSE))

# using lapply to extract the row of interest
tbls_r <- lapply(tbls_r, function(x) x[x[,1] == 'userid>=',])
```

With using `lapply`, we apply a function to each element of the list (in this case each table). `x` references a single table, so with `x[,1] == 'userid>='` I'm creating a logical vector (`TRUE` and `FALSE`) to see which values of the first column (indexed by `x[,1]` -  note I'm leaving the first position empty as I want to index all rows but only the first column) are equal to the desired string.

I then use this logical vector right away, to index the table itself, returning only the rows which have a corresponding `TRUE` value in the vector).

```
# Bind the resulting rows to a single table

result_table <- do.call(rbind,tbls_r)
```

Hope that clears it up.

---

#### Edit:

If you just want to extract the values you can use this:

`tbls_r <- sapply(tbls_r, function(x) x[x[,1] == 'userid>=',2])`

In this case, I'm specifying during indexing, that I only want the column 2, leaving me with only the values.
Also I'm using `sapply` instead of `lapply`, which already returns a handy vector instead of a list. So no need for calling `do.call`.

If you then want a `data.frame`, just go with something along the lines of

`res <- data.frame(UID = tbls_r,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Of course you can add more variables to this `data.frame` given they have the same length.

Comment: Thanks this work fine! Could you please explain what you exactly did in the third command because I still don't get it.
+ I think you are missing a ")" in the second command

Comment: one more question if I may. Is there a way to have these values horizontally instead of vertically, each value in a column? Like:
userid>= 47 1972

Comment: Sure. So you just need the values? Like a vector or you want to keep it in a table-like structure?

Comment: Thank you very much! To be honest idk what data structure is most suitable. The next step in my learning track is to 'plot' the "userid" to y axes (scatter plot) so I am not sure which one is better for plotting purposes. If they are the same then I would go for table-like structures

Comment: If you're just interested in the actual values, you can go ahead and just extract them into a vector. If you then want to plot them or whatever, you can always transform them into a `data.frame` or whatever you need. I'll update my post with a solution.